# Get first paragraph found from string containing exact matching word

Tags: c#, regex, text-mining

I'm working on the document reading module in which I have to find some words from given documents and have to pick the first paragraph in which exact word get matched.

I tried with regex, Here is a code snippet I'm using

```
    var input = "A large text with many sentences. Many sent chars in a string!. A sentence without the pattern word.";
    //Step 1: fragment phrase.
    var patternPhrase = @"(?<=(^|[.!?]\s*))[^ .!?][^.!?]+[.!?]";
    //Step 2: filter out only the phrases containing the word.
    var patternWord = @"sent";

    var result1 = Regex
    .Matches(input, patternPhrase) // step 1
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(s => s.Value)
    .Where(w => Regex.IsMatch(w, patternWord, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault(); // step 2

    Console.WriteLine("found : {0} ",result1.ToString());
```

**expected output**- "many sent chars in a string!"
**getting output**-  "A large text with many sentences."

is there any other way from which I can get exact matched words paragraph either by using regex or another one.

Comment: i edited my question, mistakenly put same in getting output before,

Comment: i want exact matching paragraph not contains once.. and patternword can be a string of words as well like "many sent", that time also it gets different output than expected one

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)[^ .!?][^?!.]*\bsent\b[^?!.]*[?!.]` See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5b%5e+.!%3f%5d%5b%5e%3f!.%5d*%5cbsent%5cb%5b%5e%3f!.%5d*%5b%3f!.%5d&i=A+large+text+with+many+sentences.+Many+sent+chars+in+a+string!.+A+sentence+without+the+pattern+word.a)

Comment: `var patternWord = @"\bsent\b";` will do the job.

Comment: ok i will try it now..

Comment: @Thefourthbird and this one also, thanks!